# Statistics for project filestypes

Tags: tree

I learnt that there was a command `cloc` to count lines of code. Now I wonder if it the file types are accurate? Should I look a the `cloc` project to know how file types are detected? The reason I wonder is that cloc seems to have false positives if I'm not mistaken when I compare the file types to the `tree|ls *.py` there is no output even though `cloc` reports python files in the current directory.

Comment: What do you think `tree|ls *.py` achieves? `ls` using `stdin` for something would be news to me. See also `ls *.py` vs `echo RTFM | ls *.py`

Comment: It counts lines of code, can't wc do that?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride It seems one way is `$ tree|grep .py` and compare with cloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the number of `.py` files in your tree to compare it to the number found by `cloc`, I’d suggest something like

```
find . -type f -name \*.py -printf '1' | wc -c
```

instead.

Comment: Thought it perhaps identified python scripts without `.py` extension from shebang, but a quick test reveals it does not. It does for for example identify `#!/bin/bash`. So depends on flavor I guess.

Comment: Yeah the thought had occurred to me too, hence my careful phrasing. I mostly wanted to avoid using `cloc` itself to validate `cloc`...

Answer (score 3):

You could increase the verbosity and get a list of identified files, for example for Python:

```
cloc -v=3 . | grep 'call_counter(.* Python)'
```

Sample output:

```
-> call_counter(./data/action_i18n_strings.py, Python)
-> call_counter(./files/usr/share/nemo/actions/myaction.py, Python)
```

And then manually verify the files by reading them.

The `call_counter` is called once for each matching file.

---

[Versions prior to 1.64](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/blob/4b421b5dba1f05a111f470913482b6706ab43e15/Unix/NEWS#L220) only identified Python scripts by checking for the extension `.py`. As of version 1.64 `cloc` identifies Python by shebang as well:

> Added python, python2.6, python2.7, python3, python3.3, python3.4
>         as script executables to identify Python files that don't end in .py.

As for [latest dev. version](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/blob/4b421b5dba1f05a111f470913482b6706ab43e15/cloc#L5750) it looks for these environments:

```
%{$rh_Language_by_Script}    = (             # {{{1
            'awk'      => 'awk'                   ,
            'bash'     => 'Bourne Again Shell'    ,
            'bc'       => 'bc'                    ,# calculator
            'crystal'  => 'Crystal'               ,
            'csh'      => 'C Shell'               ,
            'dmd'      => 'D'                     ,
            'dtrace'   => 'dtrace'                ,
            'idl'      => 'IDL'                   ,
            'kermit'   => 'Kermit'                ,
            'ksh'      => 'Korn Shell'            ,
            'lua'      => 'Lua'                   ,
            'make'     => 'make'                  ,
            'octave'   => 'Octave'                ,
            'perl5'    => 'Perl'                  ,
            'perl6'    => 'Perl'                  ,
            'perl'     => 'Perl'                  ,
            'miniperl' => 'Perl'                  ,
            'php'      => 'PHP'                   ,
            'php5'     => 'PHP'                   ,
            'python'   => 'Python'                ,
            'python2.6'=> 'Python'                ,
            'python2.7'=> 'Python'                ,
            'python3'  => 'Python'                ,
            'python3.3'=> 'Python'                ,
            'python3.4'=> 'Python'                ,
            'python3.5'=> 'Python'                ,
            'rexx'     => 'Rexx'                  ,
            'regina'   => 'Rexx'                  ,
            'ruby'     => 'Ruby'                  ,
            'sed'      => 'sed'                   ,
            'sh'       => 'Bourne Shell'          ,
            'swipl'    => 'Prolog'                ,
            'tcl'      => 'Tcl/Tk'                ,
            'tclsh'    => 'Tcl/Tk'                ,
            'tcsh'     => 'C Shell'               ,
            'wish'     => 'Tcl/Tk'                ,
            'zsh'      => 'zsh'                   ,
            );
# 1}}}
```